# template <typename T> class Array

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T>
class Array
{
public:
    Array(int size) : size(size);
    Array(const Array& right) : Array(right.size);
 virtual ~Array();

T& operator[](int index); 
T& operator[](int index) const;
```

I have problem to implement this function, can you help me?

Comment: Probably. What's the problem ?

Comment: We need more information than that, what's the problem you're having?  What errors are you getting?  Have you tried compiling it?

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to tell what your problem is, but you're not writing the constructor properly. The initialization list goes with the constructor definition, not its declaration. Either include the definition in the class definition, e.g.,

```
Array(int size) : size(size) {}
```

Or, remove the initialization list from the class definition and define it below the class:

```
template <typename T>
Array<T>::Array(int size)
: size(size)
{
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: int main()
{
//do not change this
Array<int> arr(5);
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;

cout << arr << endl;
cout << "arr.size= " << arr.get_size() << endl;

try
{
cout << arr[6] << endl;
}
catch (const out_of_range& e)
{
cout << "6 is out of range" << endl;
}

arr.sort_array();
cout << arr << endl;

return 0;
}

OUT
1 2 0 0 0
arr.size= 5
6 is out of range
0 0 0 1 2

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?